# Give contractor MySQL privileges to work on database

Tags: mysql

I have an independent contractor / freelancer helping with with some optimisation on a specific database.

I have created a new user and given them all permissions for that database.

However, they have asked for the following commands to be run and I just need to make sure I am not creating any security vulnerabilities by doing so:

```
grant super,reload on *.* to 'odeskuser_priv'@'%' identified by 'abc123'; 
grant all on mysql.* to 'odeskuser_priv'@'%' identified by 'abc123';
```

If the user "odeskuser" only has access to one database, would those commands be safe and not open any potential threats for the other dbs?

Thanks

Comment: You may wish to add an IP instead of %

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privileges-provided.html

Super grants server administration priviliges so I would say that:

```
grant super,reload on *.* to 'odeskuser_priv'@'%' identified by 'abc123';
```

Would allow that user to open threads to any DB on the server due to the `*.*` which denotes any DB and any table on the server.

Edit:

In fact super is very dangerous to give globally:

> The SUPER privilege enables an account to use CHANGE MASTER TO, KILL
>   or mysqladmin kill to kill threads belonging to other accounts (you
>   can always kill your own threads), PURGE BINARY LOGS, configuration
>   changes using SET GLOBAL to modify global system variables, the
>   mysqladmin debug command, enabling or disabling logging, performing
>   updates even if the read_only system variable is enabled, starting and
>   stopping replication on slave servers, specification of any account in
>   the DEFINER attribute of stored programs and views, and enables you to
>   connect (once) even if the connection limit controlled by the
>   max_connections system variable is reached.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are granting write access to the mysql internal database, I believe that they could add rows to the grants table and give themselves any other permissions they wanted. Super is also dangerous as Sammaye noted.